# Scatter plot with hues in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

i have a dataset in the form of

[image]

I want to create a scatter plot between x and y, colored by country in matplotlib.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
c_map = {'US': 'b', 'UK': 'r', ...}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=[c_map[_] for _ in country])
```

Comment: Basically my dataset is in the form of a pandas dataframe             for the c_map variable , i used                 c_map=P['country'].to_dict                                            and then used the rest of the suggestion.  But there is an error  'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: i tried plt.plot(df['x'],df['y'],c=df['country']), there is no error but the chart does not pop up

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code and it seems to solve the problem.

```
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   for dd,daata in P.groupby('Country'):
   ax.plot(daata['X'],daata['Y'],'o')
```

Answer (score -1):

Solving this in Altair.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cat = ["US"] *5 + ["UK"]*4
x = np.append(np.arange(1,6), np.arange(2.5,4.1,0.5))
y = np.random.randint(12,24, size=len(cat))
df = pd.DataFrame({"cat":cat, "x":x, "y":y})

from altair import *
Chart(df).mark_point().encode(x='x', y='y', color='cat').configure_cell(width=200, height=150)
```

[image]